# Change tab stop size in rendered HTML using Qt's QLabel class

Tags: c++, html, qt, rendering

I'm rendering some HTML in a QT QLabel. The HTML looks like this:

```
<pre>foo\tbar</pre>
```

(note that I've put "\t" where there is a tab chracter in the code).

This renders fine, but the tab character appears to be rendered as eight spaces, whereas I want it to be redered as 4. How can I change this **without having to change the source HTML**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4) (HTML4):

> The horizontal tab character (decimal 9 in [ISO10646] and [ISO88591]) is usually interpreted by visual user agents as the smallest non-zero number of spaces necessary to line characters up along tab stops that are every 8 characters. **We strongly discourage using horizontal tabs** in preformatted text since it is common practice, when editing, to set the tab-spacing to other values, leading to misaligned documents.

It's implementation-defined, essencially.  Most, if not all, browsers/renderers use eight spaces for tabs.  This cannot be configured in Qt.

It is, however somewhat trivial to go through your HTML and replace tabs with however many spaces you wish.  Write a simple parser for that.  Pseudocode:

```
for each <pre> block {
    for each line in block {
        position_in_line = 0

        for each character in line {
            if character is a tab {
                remove tab character

                do {
                    add a space character

                    ++position_in_line
                } while position_in_line % 8 != 0
            } else {
                ++position_in_line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case you're curious, HTML3 specifies the use of [eight-character tabs](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html):

> Within <PRE>, the tab should be interpreted to shift the horizontal column position to the next position which is a multiple of 8 on the same line; that is, col := (col+8) mod 8.

Comment: Yes, I realize that I could edit the source and replace tab characters with space characters, but I explicitly mentioned in the question that I really don't want to start editing the source HTML.

Besides, your parser pseudocode could be written a lot easier in python:

code.replace('\t', '    ')

Answer (score 2):

While `QLabel` uses a `QTextDocument` internally when rendering rich text, it does not allow access to it in it's API. However, since `QTextDocument` is a `QObject`, you can try to use

```
QTextDocument * tl = label->findChild<QTextDocument>();
```

to get access to it (will work if the `QLabel` creates the `QTextDocument` as a (direct or indirect) child of itself).

Once you have a pointer to the text document, you can use the `QTextDocument` API, e.g. `QTextOption::setTabsStop()`, to change the tab stops.

The last step is to somehow make the `QLabel` repaint itself. Probably a call to `QWidget::update()` suffices, but caching (or worse, recreating the text document) might thward that. In this case, you can register an event listener on the label to adjust the text document just prior to a `paintEvent()`, but note that the `sizeHint()` might also change when the tab stops change, so it might be more complicated still.

That said, it's how I'd approach the problem.

Comment: Sadly, the QTextdocument instance is not in the QObject parent-child tree (and access via d-ptr trickery is impossible as well, due to QLabel not having a protected ctor accepting a d-ptr), so seems like the least hackish way could be falling back to QTextBrowser, or smth...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<pre style="tab-interval:0.5in">foo\tbar</pre>
```

Could work

Comment: This does not work (with Qt 5.5.1). Also, `tab-interval` is not valid. `tab-size` will probably be useful in the future (it also doesn't work, yet).